# Check and Prevent Collision - TileEngine but units aren't bound to tiles

Tags: xna, collision-detection

The map is made by a two dimensional array of a class I made called Tile.
Each tile has smaller tiles inside of it that either collide with units, or don't.

But how can I detect and prevent collision?
Let's say The player is 6x6 smaller(mentioned above) tiles large, and one normal tile is 8x8.
How do I know that when the player is moving to the right that I know a tile is there, and move enough so they won't overlap?

As required by the rules.. I need to show effort, so this is what I have so far:
If the player is 6x6 and one tile is 8x8, then that means the player will either be on one tile, or be between 2 tiles; when he is standing between tiles(Units aren't bound to tiles). So let's say the player is in between two tiles, and wants to move right:
I check the collision of the tile right of the first (of two tiles the player is in) tile, then I check the second. To be able to move right, both must be empty.

But if a unite is say 10x10 large, then It can be in 2 tiles, or 3 max. How do I constantly check collision if I know that sizes of each unit are different, and aren't constant.

Basically, I need help with the stuff above, or a new collision method.

Comment: XNA has a Rectangle class, which has `.Intersects(Rectangle)` method that will tell you if two rectangles intersect. Just find a way to get the bounds of a tile and player in their current locations and use that method to see if they intersect.

Comment: Yes, I got that far, but I don't know how to prevent the collision, so they won't overlap.

Comment: You mean prevent collision or resolve it after it's been detected? [There are many questions on this topic here already](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collision-detection), maybe you can find your answer there.

Comment: What's the difference? I mean don't they both prevent the two objects from touching, sorry for noob question.

Comment: Detection detects, resolution resolves :) You can either prevent the collision from ever happening, or you can resolve it after it has happened. See some other questions on this topic.

Comment: I want to prevent it from happening, I'll check some other questions in the meantime. But if someone happens to come by, and knows how to prevent it or resolve it, please help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26330/discussion-between-user2066764-and-user1306322)

Comment: Alright, I'm there. How come I can't find anything similar to what I'm looking for? I want to collide units of random sizes with tiles of the same size.

Comment: You probably want to intersect Rectangles of different sizes, which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it is the smaller tiles that cause collisions, not the larger ones. In this case, you can simply iterate through all of the small tiles the unit would cross in a given move, stopping if you encounter one that would halt the unit's progress.
As an example, here is a method that would handle moving a unit right:

```
void moveUnitRight(Unit unit, int tilesRight)
{
    for(int col = unit.Right + 1 ; col <= unit.Right + tilesRight ; col++)
        {
            for(int row = unit.Top ; row <= unit.Bottom ; row++)
            {
                 if (tiles[row,col].Collides)  //stop unit here
                 {
                     unit.Right = col - 1;    //set position to tile left of collision
                     return;   //search no further
                 }
            }
     }
     //if you reach this point, no collision was detected
     unit.Right += tilesRight;    //move the full distance
}
```

Once you understand this, you could write a more robust method that handles movement in any direction as well as checking for map boundaries.